# Java multidimensional array and scanner novice Q

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm new to Java and trying to in essence implement a grid with a character, and if the user inputs 'w' 'a' 's' or 'd' the character moves up/down/left/right within the plane.

I created a multidimensional array sized 10x10 
    public static String[][] grid = new String[10][10];

And then just used a for loop to print "*"s in a 10x10 grid, except for grid[a][b] which is equal to character "A" i.e. my thing to be moved around.

That seemed to work alright, then I needed to detect the 'wasd' input from the user so I set up a:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (in.hasNext())
```

And I had then:

```
String s = in.next();
char ch = s.charAt(0);
switch (ch)
```

but I couldn't make this work, and it wasn't because I didn't complete the "switch" statement, I did, I just see it void copying and pasting the entire thing.

I'm sure its incredibly easy slight thing I am missing, can you please point it out for me?

Comment: You're trying to poll for input, which is a Bad Idea and won't work because as soon as there isn't any input, the polling loop exits.

Comment: You may need to post your code for the switch as well. A basic question, did you have break statements for each case?

Comment: Make sure that `while (in.hasNext())` includes the switch statement not just `String s = in.next();`. I mean, you should enclose the entire code between 2 braces `while (in.hasNext()){/* THE CODE */}`.

Answer (score 0):

Test the value of s :

```
if(!s.isEmpty(){ // Java 6<br>
// Your code
..;
```

}

then the switch is OK with 'char'.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I am guessing when you say it doesn't work you mean some input get ignored?

I would write the code as follow:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
   char ch = (char)in.nextByte();
   switch(ch) 
    ....
}
```

Of course, this assumes you are inputting ASCII char only.